# Angular - swapping out template depending on whether device is mobile or desktop

Tags: angular, mobile, desktop

I have been following this guide [here](https://medium.com/@thatisuday/create-separate-mobile-version-in-angular-4-4ba5d5d825ff) on swapping out an Angular view if it is a mobile/desktop. I quite like the approach and would like to use it in my application. Consequently, I have written the following pseudocode.

```
import { mobile } from '../../providers/mobile/mobile';
@Component({
   selector: 'app-landing',
   templateUrl: (mobile) ? './page.component.mobile.html' : './page.component.html',
   styleUrls: [(mobile) ? './page.component.mobile.css' : './page.component.css']
})
```

In `mobile.ts` (this isn't really correct... but its a rough idea of what i want to achieve but in a Angular fashion... I used this approach in AngularJS)

```
this.mobile = (function () {
  var check = false;
  (function (a) {
    if (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) { check = true; }
  })(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera);
  return check;
})();
```

My only concern is how to I make the mobile property being imported from the mobile file dynamic and not a constant... ie `export const mobile = true;`? I want the device detection to take place there somehow and either assign a mobile or desktop template depending on the outcome. What would be the best way of going around this? `mobile` in this instance would be a boolean that either returns true/false.

Comment: I think it'll be problematic for AOT. You'll end up loose mobile detection when you do `ng build --prod`

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. What would you recommend? How do I alternate between views dependent on the user's device?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of achieving in @decorators level. Why can't we do this in template file.

**Approach 1:**

```
<ng-template #mobile>
This is mobile
</ng-template>

<ng-template #desktop>
This is desktop
</ng-template>

<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="windows ? mobile : desktop"></ng-container>
```

**Approach 2:**

You can create 2 components, one for desktop and another one for mobile.You can dynamically inject into the DOM using View Container Ref.

To check Mobile or Desktop, we can use browser user agent with regex.

```
const regex_mobile = new RegExp(/Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|Opera Mini|IEMobile/, 'i');
window.isDesktop = !regex_mobile.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
```

You can use window.isDesktop in component and assign to public variable, which can be accessed in templates.

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer decorator level. Is there any reason why this is not correct. Also how would I determine whether or not the device that the user is on is a mobile?

Comment: ITs possible if you are using JIT compilation. Because Angular will perform compilation at runtime. If you are using AOT compilation, Angular will perform compilation at build time which angular can''t able to identify whether you are using mobile or desktop.

Comment: const regex_mobile = new RegExp(/Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|Opera Mini|IEMobile/, 'i');window.isDesktop = !regex_mobile.test(window.navigator.userAgent); You can use window.isDesktop in component and assign to public variable, which can be accessed in templates.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please add this to the answer above?