# How to render multiple templates up to a condition in angular templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angular

I need if is devise is mobile then render will be one HTML file and if is a desktop then render will be another HTML file. Below is my component file of code here that provide a JIT compilation error. Please help if have any effective ideas.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, OnDestroy, Input, AfterViewInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductSearch, Supplier } from '../../product-models/inventory.models';
import { FORMAT_SEARCH } from '../../../../../globals/_classes/functions';
import { InventoryService } from '../../inventory-serveice/inventory.service';
import { Category } from '../../../settings/models/category.models';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { CartService } from '../../../../cart-service/cart.service';
import { ProductListService } from '../product-service/product-list.service';
import { DeviceDetectorService } from 'ngx-device-detector';

console.log('window.isMobile !!!', window['isMobile']);

let VarTemp = ''; 
if(window['isMobile'] == true){
  VarTemp = './product-search-test.component.html'; 
}else{
  VarTemp = './product-search.component.html';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'product-search',
  templateUrl: VarTemp,
  styleUrls: ['../product-list.component.css']
})
```

Comment: Is this useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52781579/angular-swapping-out-template-depending-on-whether-device-is-mobile-or-desktop

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the same template for both devices, then in this unique template add angular templates to manage displayment according current device.

Comment: This way I can't use it for my project. This way increases my project of code complexity. I need to use HTML and CSS files completely differently. How can I do it